# C# query only when textbox is edited

Tags: c#

I have a query that work on a great data table. The code for the query is:

```
var getExtInv = snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date).ToList();
var query = (from c in getExtInv
             join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice
             select new {c.idexternal_invoices,
                         c.businessname,
                         o.number,
                         c.message,
                         c.price,
                         c.date,
                         c.tipologiaPagamento,
                         c.esitoPagamento,
                         c.iduser
                        }).ToList();
```

I need to filter this query with a number of textbox value that can be empty. An example for one search filter is:

```
 if (txtIdUser.Text != "")
 {
    int idUserSel = Convert.ToInt32(txtIdUser.Text);
    query = query.Where(x => x.iduser == idUserSel).ToList();
 }
```

the problem is that with this approach initially load a very high number of data which then filter based on the presence or absence of textfield filled. In doing so the initial loading time is very long. How can I speed up the process?

Thanks to all

Comment: Leave off the `ToList()` calls, as this will put all the data into memory, causing later queries to also run in memory (instead of in database). Just have a single `ToList()` at the very end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, don't use `.ToList`, `.ToArray`, `.Count`, etc. before you are ready to use the results.

```
int i = 0; 
var query = from c in snd.external_invoices.OrderByDescending(x => x.date)
            join o in snd.invoices on c.idexternal_invoices equals o.id_external_invoice
            select new {c.idexternal_invoices, c.businessname, o.number, c.message,
                        c.price, c.date, c.tipologiaPagamento, c.esitoPagamento, c.iduser };

if(int.TryParse(txtIdUser.Text, out i) // this will check if text is not empty and valid int
    query = query.Where(x => x.iduser == i);
```

and at the end when you are ready to use the results:

```
var results = query.ToList();
```